# Kafka: How to retrieve a response from consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka

I wish to describe the following scenario: 
I have a node.js backend application (It uses a single thread event loop).
This is the general architecture of the system:
Producer -> Kafka -> Consumer -> Database

Let's say that the producer sends a message to Kafka, and the purpose of this message is the make a certain query in database and retrieve the query result.
However, as we all know Kafka is an asynchronous system. If the producer sends a message to Kafka, it gets a response that the message has been accepted by a Kafka broker. Kafka broker doesn't wait until the consumer polls the message and processes it.

In this case, how can the producer get the query result operated on the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flow using Kafka will look like this:

[image: Kafka flow]

The only way of the **Producer A** be aware of what happened with the message consumed by the **Consumer A** is producing another message. Which will be handled accordingly by any other consumer available (in this case, **Consumer B**).

As you already mentioned, this flow is asynchronous. This can be useful when you have a very heavy processing on your query, like a report generation or something like that, and the second producer will notify an user inbox for example.

If that is not the case, perhaps you should use HTTP, which is synchronous and you will have the response at the end of processing.

Comment: This solution is not scalable: to have the right solution for the right producer/consumer, you should have a topic in the broker for each of the producers, otherwise, another producer might have the response. Other options are more suitable and scalable. For example, SSE (Server Sent Events) might be a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

You must generate **new flow** for communicate the query result:

```
Consumer (now its a producer) -> Kafka topic -> Producer (now its a consumer)
```

You should consider using another **synchronous communication mechanism like HTTP**.